# How can I determine if a Soundcloud track is a preview (Soundcloud GO) based on its URL?

Tags: soundcloud

My app retrieves tracks from Soundcloud and plays them.

But since a few weeks, it seems that Soundcloud has changed the way it works; and now I often get "preview" tracks; so I can only listen to 30s.

I would like to invalidate those tracks in my app.

Is there a way to do this ?
It seems there is nothing in the URL that permits to recognize those tracks.  Maybe I have to do an API call it.

I'm searching for the most basic solution possible.

Thanks !

Comment: This isn't really a programming question but rather a question about how a particular SoundCloud policy is implemented.

Comment: Well, why ?  I'm trying to find a way to identify a spec of a track. Seems quite a programming question to me :)